# Javascript: Loop Through every child node

Tags: javascript, jquery

so for example i have a brunch of pages create by easytab which looks like below in HTML

```
<div class="tab-page1 identify">//something</div>

<div class="tab-page2 identify">//something</div>

<div class="tab-page3 identify">//something</div>

<div class="tab-page4 identify">//something</div>
```

And I'd like to add something in to the contents so i created a function like below

```
$(".identify").html("123");
```

I know i can do something like to add something in the last child but i'd like to add 123 in every child how may i do it?

```
$(".identify:last-child").html("123");
```

Answer (score 1):

> And I'd like to add something in to the contents
>
> but i'd like to add 123 in every child how may i do it?

You can use [`.html(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) to add new `html` to existing `html` content.

```js
$(".identify").html(function(index, html) {
  return html + 123
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-page1 identify">//something</div>

<div class="tab-page2 identify">//something</div>

<div class="tab-page3 identify">//something</div>

<div class="tab-page4 identify">//something</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to iterate each found node and perform a function:

```
$(".identify").each(function(){
    $(this).html("123");
});
```

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbp31fjn/1/)

Comment: i am using easyTab so this seem only works on the first page

Comment: Can you post a more complete example that demos this?

Comment: `$(".identify").html("123");` has the same result, the `.each()` part is redundant.

Comment: @Steve _"And I'd like to add something in to the contents"_

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to achieve this.Check it

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $(".identify").html("123");
    });
});
</script>


<div class="tab-page1 identify">//something</div>

<div class="tab-page2 identify">//something</div>

<div class="tab-page3 identify">//something</div>

<div class="tab-page4 identify">//something</div>

<button id="btn">Do it</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the **append** to add something to the existing content:

```
$(".identify").each(function(){
    $(this).append("123");
});
```